# SSL to TLS switch - httpd RHEL 5.11

Tags: apache, ssl, rhel5, poodle-attack

I am planning to disable SSL protocol in my site and moving to the TLS secure protocol. I will be making the configuration change in httpd. Does it require any changes to the server and client certificates or credentials which are already in place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it doesn't. Only the `supportedProtocols` needs to change.